# Limit UDP traffic with iptables

Tags: ntp

I have set the limit to UDP traffic with this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 1000 -j ACCEPT
```

Now, from time to time, I see that ntpd service fails to sync with remote servers. I definitely do not want to make the rule less strict, as --limit 1/s surely must be enough for ntpd syncing.

Is there some kind of extra traffic going from ntpd?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you please be more specific? Update the heading to make sure that it reflects on the question you have, not just a general topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The udp limiting rule used is non-specific, so you might well have issues with ntpd syncing if the packet comes immediately after other unrelated udp packets that caused the limiter to engage. One suggestion would be to allow source port 123 specifically:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 123 -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 1000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 1000 -j ACCEPT
```

Another, more secure suggestion would be only allow the packet if it is in response to a solicitation started by you (perhaps then followed by your original rule):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Exactly! I've just had to add rule to 123 port to allow it. Thanks.